# Неправильная сумма постфиксного инкремента

Tags: c++, операторы, стандарт

Почему итог равен 8?

```
int inkrement = 5;
inkrement = inkrement + 1;
cout << inkrement << "\n";

inkrement++; // inkrement
cout << inkrement << "\n"; // = 7

inkrement--; // - 1 = 6
cout << inkrement << endl;

cout << inkrement++ << endl; // = 6
cout << "Итог:" << ++inkrement << endl; // = 7
```

Comment: Ну дык после последнего `inkrement++` в переменной будет `7`, хотя он и печатает `6`.

Comment: Должно выводить 6 7 6 6 8 - так? если так, то меняйте заголовок вопроса, сумма правильная, выводит правильно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int inkrement = 5;

inkrement = inkrement + 1;
```

Теперь значение 6.

```
cout << inkrement << "\n";

inkrement++; // inkrement
```

Теперь *хранящееся* значение 7, его и выводим...

```
cout << inkrement << "\n"; // = 7

inkrement--; // - 1 = 6
```

Теперь *хранящееся* значение опять 6, его и выводим...

```
cout << inkrement << endl;
```

Далее *хранящееся* значение становится 7, но значение выражения с постфиксным инкрементом - это значение до инкремента, выводит 6.

```
cout << inkrement++ << endl; // = 6
```

В последней строке хранящееся значение сначала увеличивается (префиксный!), становится 8, и потом выводится.

```
cout << "Итог:" << ++inkrement << endl; // = 7
```

Итак, 6 7 6 6 8...